# if we have to use ListView Command Extension button not only one library or list but all the over the site from that one button so how can we do

Tags: listviewcommandset

[image: command one button i have created using list view command extension]

I have created a Command Button in Ribbon below rename. I have to use this single button or functionality in every library are there in my site. so how can do this in the list view command extension

Answer (score 0):

In order to associate the custom action with document libraries, the `RegistrationId` must be set to `101` (because for document library Template ID is 101 and for List templated id is 100)

You can change this value in `/SharePoint/assets/element.xml` file as shown in below:

```
<CustomAction
        Title="SPFxListViewCommandSet"
        RegistrationId="101"
        RegistrationType="List"
        Location="ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar"
        ClientSideComponentId="5fc73e12-8085-4a4b-8743-f6d02ffe1240"
        ClientSideComponentProperties="{&quot;sampleTextOne&quot;:&quot;One item is selected in the list.&quot;, &quot;sampleTextTwo&quot;:&quot;This command is always visible.&quot;}">
    </CustomAction>
```

Read more information about it at below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api#add-a-listview-command-set-to-a-solution-package-for-deployment

> Note
>
> In order to associate the custom action with document libraries, the
> RegistrationId must be set to 101. If you would like the action to
> work on both lists and document libraries, another CustomAction must
> be added to the elements.xml file